# configure Debug configurations for Maven project in intelliJ on ubuntu

Tags: maven, debugging, intellij-idea, groovy

Groovy SDK is not configured for module

How to debug the Groovy test cases in Intellij and configuration settings
for Maven project

Comment: Is here really relevant? As in does it not work *only* in ubuntu?

Comment: Please see if https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-groovy.html#add_groovy_support helps.